# Extracting text inside body of mail using javamail API stopping after first iteration

Tags: jakarta-mail, multipart, stalled

I've searched for hours and tried everything to fix this code. I've been working with the example below and after updating appropriate variables this works fine through till the end of processing the first email. It seems to pause indefinitely. I had to alter code at (//check if the content is an inline image) as variables appear to need declaration before they were used but have not changed anything apart from that. Any help before I loose my mind will be much appreciated.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Original code at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_fetching_emails.htm

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

My code below... (output below that)

```
package com.mail.coder;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class FetchingEmail2 {

   public static void fetch(String pop3Host, String storeType, String user,
      String password) {
      try {
          // create properties field
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
          properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);
          properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
          properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
          Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
          // emailSession.setDebug(true);

         // create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
         Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

         store.connect("mail.DOMAIN.com", "USERNAME@DOMAIN.com", "PASS");

         // create the folder object and open it
         Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
         emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));

         // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
         Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
         System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

         for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            writePart(message);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if ("YES".equals(line)) {
               message.writeTo(System.out);
            } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
               break;
            }
         }

         // close the store and folder objects
         emailFolder.close(false);
         store.close();

      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

          String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
          String mailStoreType = "pop3";
          String username = 
             "abc@gmail.com";// change accordingly
          String password = "*****";// change accordingly

          //Call method fetch
          fetch(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
   }

   /*
   * This method checks for content-type 
   * based on which, it processes and
   * fetches the content of the message
   */
   public static void writePart(Part p) throws Exception {
      if (p instanceof Message)
         //Call method writeEnvelope
         writeEnvelope((Message) p);

      System.out.println("----------------------------");
      System.out.println("CONTENT-TYPE: " + p.getContentType());

      //check if the content is plain text
      if (p.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
         System.out.println("This is plain text");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         System.out.println((String) p.getContent());
      } 
      //check if the content has attachment
      else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
         System.out.println("This is a Multipart");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
         int count = mp.getCount();
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            writePart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
      } 
      //check if the content is a nested message
      else if (p.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
         System.out.println("This is a Nested Message");
         System.out.println("---------------------------");
         writePart((Part) p.getContent());
      } 
      //check if the content is an inline image
      else if (p.isMimeType("image/jpeg")) {
         System.out.println("--------> image/jpeg");
         Object o = p.getContent();

         InputStream x = (InputStream) o;
         // Construct the required byte array
         System.out.println("x.length = " + x.available());
         **int i;
         byte[] bArray = new byte[x.available()];**

         while ((i = (int) ((InputStream) x).available()) > 0) {
            int result = (int) (((InputStream) x).read(bArray));
            if (result == -1)
         i = 0;
            break;
         }
         FileOutputStream f2 = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/image.jpg");
         f2.write(bArray);
      } 
      else if (p.getContentType().contains("image/")) {
         System.out.println("content type" + p.getContentType());
         File f = new File("image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
         DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f)));
            com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream test = 
                 (com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream) p
                  .getContent();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int bytesRead;
         while ((bytesRead = test.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
      } 
      else {
         Object o = p.getContent();
         if (o instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("This is a string");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println((String) o);
         } 
         else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
            System.out.println("This is just an input stream");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            InputStream is = (InputStream) o;
            is = (InputStream) o;
            int c;
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
               System.out.write(c);
         } 
         else {
            System.out.println("This is an unknown type");
            System.out.println("---------------------------");
            System.out.println(o.toString());
         }
      }

   }
   /*
   * This method would print FROM,TO and SUBJECT of the message
   */
   public static void writeEnvelope(Message m) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("This is the message envelope");
      System.out.println("---------------------------");
      Address[] a;

      // FROM
      if ((a = m.getFrom()) != null) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
      }

      // TO
      if ((a = m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
         for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
         System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
      }

      // SUBJECT
      if (m.getSubject() != null)
         System.out.println("SUBJECT: " + m.getSubject());

   }

}
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Output

```
messages.length---5
---------------------------------
This is the message envelope
---------------------------
FROM: Jack Frost <sender@gmail.com>
TO: recipient@domain.com
SUBJECT: another email
----------------------------
CONTENT-TYPE: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000096c73056991868c"
This is a Multipart
---------------------------
----------------------------
CONTENT-TYPE: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
This is plain text
---------------------------
testing

----------------------------
CONTENT-TYPE: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
This is a string
---------------------------
<div dir="ltr">testing</div>
```

Comment: OK after adding some traps looks like reder.readline() has some issue

for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
Message message = messages[i];
System.out.println("---------------------------------");
writePart(message);
System.out.println("-------------passed writepart--------------------");
String line = reader.readLine(); // <---GETTING STUCK HERE
System.out.println("-------------passed stringline--------------------");

Comment: I decided to comment out the code block containing - String line = reader.readLine(); Also commented out the code for inline image, input stream etc. I only needed the mixed mime and string sections and now emails coming through nicely. Will revisit when necessary. Thanks for the views.

Comment: You understand that it's pausing indefinitely because it's reading from stdin (System.in), right?  Did you copy this code from someone else without understanding what it does?

Comment: Correct. I don't know much about Java and was working with another developer who was stuck on this one too. I mentioned where this code came from and it appears to be widely used but I've found a heap of people have similar issues with understanding whats going on behind the scenes with (System.in)... Is there a way to see what's happening...?

Comment: It's reading from the terminal.   You have to type YES or QUIT.  If this isn't clear, you need to go back to Java 101.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Shannon. Went back to basics and been 'crawling before walking'. Getting there now and it's starting to sink in.